# createTextNode in JS is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, console, createtextnode

I am trying out a simple exercise, in which I want to append a

, generated by JavaScript to a div with an id of "target-area". 
The problem is Chrome refuses to inject this paragraph and gives me a error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'createTextNode'

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="target-area">
        <p id="tagline">Hello World!</p>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

        // store the target area to a variable to keep things neat
        var targetArea = document.getElementById("target-area");
        // create our <p> element
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        // create a text node inside the <p>, note that we're using a variable "p" here
        var snippet = p.createTextNode("this was a generated paragraph");
        // insert our generated paragraph into the DOM
        targetArea.appendChild(snippet);

    </script>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**document has the createTextNode** property and not the element that was just created

So basically your code should look like this..

```
    // store the target area to a variable to keep things neat
    var targetArea = document.getElementById("target-area");
    // create our <p> element
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    // create a text node inside the <p>, note that we're 
    //  using a variable "p" here
   var snippet = document.createTextNode("this was a generated paragraph");
    // insert our generated paragraph into the DOM
    p.appendChild(snippet);
    targetArea.appendChild(p);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/VHhQF/)**

Comment: so how should I modify the code? I tried everything and even more, I am copying this from a JS book...

Answer (score 0):

just out of curiosity.

Why not simply?

```
// store the target area to a variable to keep things neat
var targetArea = document.getElementById("target-area");
// create our <p> element
var p = document.createElement("p");
// create a text node inside the <p>, note that we're 
//  using a variable "p" here
var snippet = document.createTextNode("this was a generated paragraph");
// insert our generated paragraph into the DOM
targetArea.appendChild(snippet);
```